# jquery modal('hide') method is not working in reactJs

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a login modal that is toggled by a button with `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes. After doing the authentication, I need to close the modal so I used `$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide')` but it doesn't work and throw this error instead:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.$) is not a function
    at onSubmit (Login.js:30:1)
    at createFormControl.ts:1048:1
onSubmit @ Login.js:30
(anonymous) @ createFormControl.ts:1048
await in (anonymous) (async)
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4161
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4210
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4274
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4288
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9038
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9070
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9083
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9094
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9285
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26096
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3988
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9284
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6462
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6454
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6427
```

My modal JSX code:

```
<div class="modal" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Login</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input {...register("email", { required: true, pattern: /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/g })} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                                {errors.email?.type === 'required' && <FormErrorMsg message="Email is required" />}
                                {errors.email?.type === 'pattern' && <FormErrorMsg message="Invalid email" />}
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input {...register("password", { required: true })} type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                                {errors.password?.type === 'required' && <FormErrorMsg message="Password is required" />}
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How I handle the onSubmit event:

```
const onSubmit = data => {
        async function fetchLogin (){
            let rs = await login(data.email, data.password);
        
            return rs;
        }

        let loginSuccess = fetchLogin();

        if (loginSuccess) {
            dispatch(loginAction());
            $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide');
        }
    }
```

Could you please help me with this? Thank you very much for your precious time.

Comment: A tip, you should drop jQuery if using react, the library manipulates the DOM whereas react works with a shadow DOM. these 2 ways of editing the content are at odds with each other. So my advice to you would be to drop jQuery and use react libraries to handle animation.

Answer (score 0):

I have used another library that comes with `modal` component, react-bootstrap for specific and that solved the problem. I handle the animation using javascript instead of jquery and that is a lot easier.